# CASE function for multiple instances

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am looking to return a table with each column tagging whether or not a user used a certain product in a given month. The data appears as below:

```
User    Date        Product
001     1/1/2019    A
001     1/1/2019    A
001     1/1/2019    B
002     1/1/2019    A
002     1/1/2019    A
003     1/1/2019    C
004     1/1/2019    A
004     1/1/2019    B
004     1/1/2019    C
```

I would like the SQL code to result in this (i.e. a column for each product type, with a 1 or 0 if that product appeared in the row in the data):

```
User    A   B   C
001     1   1   0
002     1   0   0
003     0   0   1
004     1   1   1
```

Currently I only end up with only a single 1 in each column, even when multiple instances exist. (This is in SQL Server)

Thanks!

Comment: MySQL or SQL Server? They are different products...

Comment: you state requirement is for a given month yet that data is all same date so no ability to differentiate and you output table does not indicate/show if you need data from several months. 
I am assuming the query needs to pull data just for a given month?

Comment: And do you really only have three products? Or do you need the query to dynamically arrange the columns depending on the products discovered that month?

Comment: The real data set has 9 products, but the columns should be consistent (just 1 or 0 if the product exists for that user)

Comment: This is just an example. The data set I am using has multiple months, but I am only looking at data for a single month

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select user,
       max(case when product = 'A' then 1 else 0 end) as a,
       max(case when product = 'B' then 1 else 0 end) as b,
       max(case when product = 'C' then 1 else 0 end) as c
from  t
group by user
```

Comment: I had originally used COUNT(CASE... but Max seems to work. I wonder why

Comment: @ryans1, do you know how to add a where clause for a given month?

Comment: @DaniDev . . . You would just add a `where` clause before the `group by`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, yep just wanted to make sure he (@ryans1)  had all he needed.